# How to animate a div into 3d on the hover of the mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my div to pop out in a 3d manner when hovering over it. Will somebody please help. I prefer it in vanilla javascript.

Comment: maybe make it have a shadow in the background

Comment: You don't want to use jQuery?

Comment: @Perumal93 because it is a library and I would rather build off of normal js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for JavaScript if you just want to have a shadow on mouse hover. And maybe move it up slightly and add a smooth transition too, all with css only:

```
div {
  transition: .2s ease-out;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  transform: translate3d(0,-2px,0);
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle for above code and play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/b0byf4by/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think the *box-shadow property* would be the best way; there is a *perspective property* that could probably do it, but it might be overkill.

**Add a class (on mouseover) with javascript that adds a box shadow to that particular div.**

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

*http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp*